Where does the pressure go when the fluid leaved the pipe?
I have an elementary question on Bernoulli's law. Consider the pipe as depicted below.

At point $1$, the pipe has the cross-section $A_1$ and the incompressible, non-viscous fluid is flowing with the speed $v_1$. The pipe lies horizontally and we assume no external pressure, so we have only dynamic pressure:
$$
p = \frac{1}{2} \rho v_1^2
$$
At point $2$, the pipe is wider, having the cross-section $A_2$, so the fluid needs to slow down in order to keep the flow constant:
$$
v_2 = \frac{A_1}{A_2} v_1
$$
According to the Bernoulli's law, this must lead to the increase of the static pressure inside the pipe, in order to keep the total pressure, static+dynamic, constant:
$$
p = \frac{1}{2} \rho v_1^2 = p_2 + \frac{1}{2} \rho v_2^2
$$
Now, to my understanding of the Pascal's law, $p_2$ must act in all directions, right? If yes, what happens to the pressure $p_2$ at point $3$, once the fluid leaves the pipe? I understand that it carries potential energy, and energy must be conserved. So does the pressure force the fluid to spread sidewards and up/downwards, adding a transversal velocity component to the fluid's flow? Does the fluid stream disintegrate into drops? Anything else?

If the pressure at $3$ and $1$ are both atmospheric, the fluid is not going to move.  If you want the fluid to move the pressure at $1$ will have to be larger than atmospheric.

Would it be unrealistic to just assume that the fluid is flowing at point $1$, no matter why? Perhaps it came initially from a reservoir positioned above, so that hydrostatic pressure due to gravity caused it to move, but all that pressure has been converted into the dynamic pressure.

As  your Bernoulli calculation shows ,the fluid at 1 and 3 must have different pressures. If 3 is open to the air, the pressure at 3 is 1atm. (Bernoulli assumes no friction, incompressible, and time-independent $v$)

The assumption of time independent $v$ shopws what the problem is: If you assume that the fluid is intially moving, than, with the equal pressures  it will be slowing down in time. Then you will get a consistent Bernoulli after you add the $\partial \phi/\partial t$ term that the time-dependent Bernoulli requires.

@IgorF. the driving force for fluid flow is a pressure difference.  Therefore, it is indeed unrealistic to assume that there is no pressure difference between points 1 and 3.


Your picture is incorrect. Because there is only atmospheric pressure and no higher pressure, it is impossible for water to fill the pipes in the divergent section.

This picture is correct, water does not fill the pipe, it keeps moving forward. Fluid will not fill pipes without reason. After passing through the divergent section, if your horizontal pipe is very long and creates a pressure difference, then the water in the divergent section may fill the pipe.

Thanks for pointing this out, this really helps.

@IgorF. To fill the pipe you give with water, the direction of motion must be changed during the process from section 1 to section 2, and changing the direction of motion requires a pressure difference. Without pressure difference, direction cannot be changed.
